# How to locate which application downloaded files to my computer?

Tags: ssh, files, arch-linux, security, aur

I was doing a routine system clean-up today and I noticed that in my Downloads folder there are 4 files(adult videos no less) that I did not download.

How can I find out where they came from/what app added them to my computer. Any method to check if I had any incoming connections I was unaware of? Maybe in systemd's journal or dmesg? I have openSSH installed, but the server wasn't setup and by default it doesn't allow connections. Also sometime in the last couple of days I tested lbry.tv's app from [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=lbry-desktop-git) AUR pkg which doesn't seem to install any oddities.

I have to note that noone has access to my computer besides me.

I'm running on `5.9.14-arch1-1` kernel.

Comment: Look at the creation dates of the files (`man ls stat`). Check your logs for around those times. Check your browser's logs. Do you have a firewall (hardware or software)?

Comment: @waltinator - that helps the investigation but doesn't really point the executable that actually brought the file.  I'd say it would be interesting if we get something that logs sockets and processes in a secure way (e.g. using CGroup maybe) so that once we look at a file, we get list of sockets (and socket meta data) alongside information about the executable that was involved with it.

Comment: I've done a deep scan with rkhunter and clamav, nothing came up out of the ordinary. Logs don't show anything at the time and date the files were added to my computer. I'm not behind a firewall (I know...). I'm not sure how I could use cgroups. At this point I shreded the files and will soon reimage my system but any links with documentation on how I would go about finding the source of these is more than welcome since I want to know how to more thoroughly investigate this in any future similar problem.